Why can't I push more than two seperate chests with one piston
I am trying to move a chain of chests using pistons, but the issue is, a piston can't push if there are more than two chests placed next to each other. What's the deal? Why can't I just push the chests? I am playing the latest version of Mincaft Wii U edition.

I’d assume it’s because it just doesn’t allow you to do that by default, but I don’t really play the game so I have no idea.

It's hard to understand your current setup without a screenshot
